# Does the following system of linear equations have unique solutions? If not why? And if so, how do i obtain them?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to use the Gauss’s method to solve this problem (I'm new to linear algebra, so this is as much as I know) but I can't quite get the echelon form, despite the effort.

\begin{alignat}{5}
&3x &&+y  &&+z  &&+r  &&= a \\
&x  &&+3y &&+z  &&+r  &&= b \\
&x  &&+y  &&+3z &&+r  &&= c \\
&x  &&+y  &&+z  &&+3r &&= d
\end{alignat}

Comment: Hello, welcome to MathSE. Try to clarify your question better, for example what's the epsilon-model?

Comment: By the epsilon model, do you mean the [echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)?

Comment: Do you mean this? $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{12} (5 a-b-c-d) \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{12} (-a+5 b-c-d) \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{12} (-a-b+5 c-d) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{12} (-a-b-c+5 d) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$